# Unable to create Windows agentPool with ACS-Engine

Tags: azure-container-service

I am attempting to setup a hybrid `ACS-Engine` with `Kubernetes`. I am able to setup the `Linux agentPool` successfully. When I add the `Windows agentPool`, I receive an error. I only get this when `osType` is `Windows`.

I am using the following to setup the agentPools:

```
"agentPoolProfiles": [
  {
    "name": "linuxpool1",
    "count": 3,
    "vmSize": "Standard_D2_v2",
    "availabilityProfile": "AvailabilitySet",
    "osType": "Linux"
  },
  {
    "name": "windowspool2",
    "count": 3,
    "vmSize": "Standard_D2_v2",
    "availabilityProfile": "AvailabilitySet",
    "osType": "Windows"
  }
],
```

When the `Windows agentPool` is included, I receive the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro:acs-engine appalachios$ ./acs-engine -artifacts zeuscluster zeus_deploy_v1.json 
acsengine took 2.42314ms
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x112a551]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pkg/api/vlabs.
(*Properties).Validate(0xc420070420, 0x4ce, 0x6ce)
/Users/appalachios/gopath/src/github.com/Azure/acs-
engine/pkg/api/vlabs/validate.go:241 +0x471
github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pkg/api.LoadContainerService(0xc420077500, 0x4ce, 0x6ce, 
0xc4200159f0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x6ce)
/Users/appalachios/gopath/src/github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pkg/api/apiloader.go:73 +0x398
github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pkg/api.DeserializeContainerService(0xc420077500, 0x4ce, 0x6ce, 0x4ce, 0x6ce, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1271fc0)
/Users/appalachios/gopath/src/github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pkg/api/apiloader.go:30 +0x13a
github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pkg/api.LoadContainerServiceFromFile(0x7fff5fbffbfc, 0x13, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10b7510)
/Users/appalachios/gopath/src/github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pkg/api/apiloader.go:20 +0x1bd
main.main()
/Users/appalachios/gopath/src/github.com/Azure/acs-engine/acs-engine.go:205 +0x3c2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you might be missing windowsProfile in your input API model. E.g.:

```
"windowsProfile": {
  "adminUsername": "azureuser",
  "adminPassword": "replacepassword1234$"
}
```

I will take the feedback to return a better error message in this case. But can you confirm if you have windowsProfile in your API model that you generated the template with?

Comment: This was the problem. Once I added this, all was successful. Thank you!